# Finding function with an oblique asymptote

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Let $f$ be a function, continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, twice differentiable for $x \neq p$ for some $p \in \mathbb{R}$.
We are given that $f(
p) = 0, f(0)=-1$, it has an oblique asymptote $y=2x-1$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to p}f'(x) = \infty$.

Now, we are asked to find constants $a,b,c,d$ so that $$f(x) = (ax^3 + bx^2+cx+d)^{1/3}$$ satisfies the conditions above. I can find $a$ as $8$ using the oblique asymptote. By $f(0)=-1$, $d$ can be found as $-1$. To find some $b,c$, I plan to check the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) -2x = -1$ and use the identity $u^3 - v^3 = (u-v)(u^2 +uv +v^2)$ but it looks messy. How can I find those $b$ and $c$?

Comment: Set the first two coefficients of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ to be the same as $(2x-1)^3=8x^3-12x^2+6x-1$ to get $b$. To get $c$ you need to think about $f'(p)$, as in dfnu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finding $b$ is pretty straightforward.

Using your results, you have
$$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{8x^3+bx^2+cx-1}.$$
Now you can use the **fundamental limit**
$$\frac{(1+\alpha)^\beta-1}{\alpha} \to \beta\tag{1}\label{1}$$
when $\alpha \to 0$, to get
\begin{eqnarray}
-1 &=&\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) -2x=\\
&=& \lim_{x\to \infty} 2x\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{bx^2+cx-1}{8x^3}}-1\right)=\\
&\stackrel{\eqref{1}}{=}&\lim_{x\to \infty} 2x\cdot \frac13\cdot\frac{bx^2+cx-1}{8x^3}=\frac{b}{12}.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $b=-12$.

Since the derivative is
$$f'(x) = \frac{24x^2-24x+c}{3\sqrt[3]{(8x^3-12x^2+cx-1)^2}}$$
the requirement that $f$ is not differentiable in only one point $p$, implies that $$g(x) = 8x^3-12x^2+cx-1$$ has **only one real root**.

If you want to avoid using Cardano's method to obtain conditions on $c$, you can look analytically for the value of $c$ for which $g(x)$ has a real root with multiplicity $2$, so that we must have
$$\begin{cases}
8x^3 -12x^2+cx -1 = 0\\
24x^2-24x+c = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Replacing $c=-24x^2 +24x$ in the first equation you obtain
$$16x^3-12x^2+1=(2x-1)^2(4x+1) = 0.$$
By direct check you can see that $c=6$ gives a root $x=\frac12$ with multiplicity $3$, whereas $c=-\frac{15}2$ gives a root $x=-\frac14$ with multiplicity $2$, has required.

In conclusion all the functions
$$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{8x^3-12x^2+cx -1}$$
with $c>-\frac{15}2$ satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Is there any way to not use the fundamental limit?

Comment: Also, can you please explain how do you find this factorization $16x^3-12x^2+1=(2x-1)^2(4x+1) = 0$ without Cardano's method?

Comment: @Ninja You can use the factorization of difference of cubes as you propose, or the method proposed in the comment to OP.

Comment: @Ninja as for the factorization of the polynomial, the roots being rational, you can find them by direct search among $\pm \frac1{q}$, where $q$ is a divisor of $16$.